# How to get back to my user account?

Tags: upgrade, password

I was running Ubuntu 13.10 and I got a window indicating I could upgrade to 14.04.  I accepted the upgrade, and after the upgrade was finished I was left with an empty Unity background and a mouse pointer. After rebooting a few times without getting anything I decided to download the iso image for 14.04 and ran the installation again from the disk.

During the installation I selected the option to keep all the user files intact. The installation asked me for a username and a password.  I used my first name as username (my previous username was different, it was my nickname, but I could not remember at the time. For the password I used the same as the password I had before. Now when I sign in I don’t see any of the settings I had before. All icons are gone from the desktop and from the Unity launch bar.

When I launch *Files* I can see "computer" file system and I can still see the home folder and under that I can see a folder with my new username and another with my previous username. This folder has all my files in it (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, etc.). I tried creating a user with my nickname (the same name as that folder) and used the same password, but I cannot login with it.

I need help getting back as that user so that I can see all the apps and environment as I used to. Can someone help?

Comment: I will try this tonight when I get in from work. I appreciate your reply. I hope this gives me back my environment and things will look just as before. 
I will let you know as soon as I try it.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your previous user's folder as root (launch `sudo nautilus` from Terminal). Inside, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (will show hidden files and folders), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (will select them all), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (will copy to the clipboard). Then go inside your new user's folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste). Answer <kbd>Yes</kbd> to the questions given to overwrite newly created files.

Then, open Terminal inside your home folder and type:

```
sudo chown -R new_user:new_user new_user/
```

Where `new_user` is your new user's name.

Next, I'm going to do this in terminal fully. My old name was `hopungo` and new is `Danatela`:

```
cd /home
sudo cp -r hopungo/* Danatela/
sudo chown -R Danatela:Danatela Danatela/
sudo rm -rf hopungo
```